# After system upgrade (Open SUSE Tumbleweed), I get consistent symbol lookup errors related to /usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.30

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, gnutls, nettle

After updating my Open SUSE Tumbleweed system, I get consistent errors relating to the GNU TLS library. It has prevented me from using certain programs, while others start, but produce errors

For example, brave returns:

`/opt/brave.com/brave/brave: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.30: undefined symbol: nettle_streebog256_digest, version NETTLE_8`

And discord returns

`/home/jonah/.Discord/Discord: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.30: undefined symbol: nettle_streebog256_digest, version NETTLE_8`

They all talk about a symbol look up error, I haven't found anything relating to it online, so I assume this is a new issue with a new version of the library, given that it only occurred after I updated.

Hopefully there is an easy fix for this...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

The package `libnettle8` was on version 3.6.5, while the rest of the GNU TLS packages on my system were on 3.7.1. Updating fixed the problem!

Hopefully this can help anyone who's encountered this issue!